# Defining Thermodynamic beta in unit of second

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, units

If I define [Thermodynamic beta](http://Thermodynamic%20beta) in unit of second. Does this mean that:

1. Boltzmann constant $k$ is unit-less?
2. $T$ is in units of frequency (Hz) or Kelvin $K$?

In this case, is defining Thermodynamic beta $\beta$ in unit of second a reason to make $\hbar$ unitless? To make $\hbar$ = 1 with no unit, which originally is $1.0545718 × 10^{-34} m^2 kg s^{-1}$, should Boltzmann constant $k$ be scaled appropriately?

It seems that defining $\beta$ in dimension of time is also the "hybrid case" where c is not 1.

This is the table of Student Friendly Quantum Field Theory:
[image]

Comment: $\beta =\frac{1}{ k_B \, T}$ has the units of $J^{-1}$, so $\hbar \beta$ has the units of ${s}$. Redefining a scaled version of the Boltzmann constant by $\frac{1}{k'_B} = \frac{\hbar}{k_B}$ or $k'_B = \frac{k_B}{\hbar}$ would give $\beta' = \frac{1}{k'_B T}$ the units of $s$.

Comment: @ jim In this case, does $\hbar$ become unitless and is $T$ in units of frequency (1/Time)? $\hbar =1.0545718×10−34$ before, to make it $1$, the original value of $k$ should be divided by 1.0545718×10−34. But it seems that it is not what I see in any table. I also see temperature defined in frequency (Hz). If I plainly divide the original value of $k$ by 1.0545718×10−34 while keeping temperature, say, at 0.7K, it seems that I can still get $\hbar = 1$.

Comment: @ jim However, when most of the time I would use $\hbar$ independent of thermodynamic beta and vice versa. If I use $\hbar = 1$, which is the cause of every scaling, setting $k' =\frac{k}{\hbar}$ does work when $\hbar$ and $\beta$ is used together. But in classical statistical mechanics, no $\hbar$ appears and $\beta$ is used independently, why should $\beta$ changed just because I want to set $\hbar = 1$ unitless?

Comment: @Arnold Neumaier I just attached the table. I wonder what causes us to define $T$ in units of frequency (Hz).

Comment: @jim However, when most of the time I would use ℏ independent of thermodynamic beta and vice versa. If I use ℏ=1, which is the cause of every scaling, setting $k′=\frac{k}{\hbar}$ does work when ℏ and β is used together. But in classical statistical mechanics, no ℏ appears and β is used independently, why should ββ changed just because I want to set ℏ=1 unitless?